# May I know why there is -3 on my question. what's wrong?

Tags: support

I have a question about my Database Administrators Stack Exchange post: [MySQL database innodb tables](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/137414/mysql-database-innodb-tables)

Comment: What's wrong with it is that the question doesn't have any relevant information for people to actually give an answer

Comment: I already mentioned error whatever I received. that's wht I can provide. what else as per you I should provide?

Comment: If the error message is all that's needed to give you an answer, then you could search that message on google. Stack Exchange is for specific questions within a scope

Comment: You've deleted your question but that's not the purpose of downvotes. You've taken the course correcting action of asking on meta how to get your question fixed up, that's good. That's how the site should work. Look at the feedback we're providing. Help us better understand what the problem is, what the constraints we have to work against are. What is the minimal number of steps a person could take to reproduce your error. The database corruption isn't going to fix itself so take a breath and focus on getting your system back up and operational (if it's possible)

Comment: it was by mistake.. I did undelete quickly.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) should be your first read. And then you'll probably understand.

Answer (score 7):

The [Help Center](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) has excellent resources for how the Stack Exchange model works.

Looking at your question - what do I know?

- Something is wrong and a table is in a bad state.
- You cannot repair it as the storage engine doesn't support it
- You're using innodb

As a non-MySQL person, that question seems bereft of details. What command have you issued? Is the above the exact error message? What happened to get you into this state? etc

"Also how I can optimize mysql database?"
That is unanswerable. Optimize for what - read, write, stability, etc? What are your constraints around optimization - do you have a budget? Have you taken a benchmark to establish what your current performance is and do you know what the target should be. Etc, etc etc. Much, much too broad to be answerable and not a good fit for the site.

$.02

Comment: first of all table is not in a bad state.

Comment: Again, not a MySQL person, so why would you be running a repair on it?

Comment: Then why are you trying to repait it?

Comment: I'm getting message at frontend that your database corrupted. try to repair  it.

Comment: Your database is corrupted but that table is *not* in a bad state?

Comment: As a non-MySQL person how you can comment on question as this is related to mysql and I added tag on question.

Comment: Because this is a meta question, not about mySQL at all, but about the issues on your question

Comment: yes in meta I posted to know why question getting downvote and As a non-MySQL person how you can comment on question ?

Comment: and you got answers pertinent to that, you just don't like them

Comment: @Yesha: I believe billinkc's point is that your main site question has (or had) issues obvious even to a non-MySQL person (such as lack of details, for instance).

Comment: An automobile mechanic that specializes in Ford is probably has enough general knowledge of automobiles to speculate on what the minimum a mechanic that focuses on Tata Motors vehicles would need to know. So, can I *fix* what's wrong with your database. No. Can I help you understand what you need to supply if you want *someone* to help, **yes**

Comment: @Andriy - then I guess only mysql knowledgeably person can answer and can up/down vote..I believe mysql expert can easily understand my question. I posted in meta to know how non mysql user can downvote.

Comment: Everyone understands the question, it's just that's a bad question

Comment: bad? How? if you post your issue so is it bad question everyone asking?

Comment: Read the help center on asking questions. For the points listed on the topic ask yourself, does my question meet the criteria?

Comment: I already said why it's bad, it doesn't fit with the criteria of questions to ask on stack exchange. It literally is "I got this error message on a table, oh, and how can I optimize my database?"

Comment: Anyway it doesn't make sense to me.  jkavalik commented on question without down vote means he needed just more details to help.

Comment: I don't know how it doesn't make sense, but if you don't want to listen to the advice posted here then I fail to understand why were you asking in meta in the first place

Comment: Also covered in the Help Center is that voting is anonymous - you do not know whether jkavalik voted on your question at all, much less whether their vote was positive or negative. You came to meta asking why your question had -3. I have attempted to provide general purpose guidance to help you understand why it might be so. I feel that rather than taking this constructive criticism to heart, you are fighting and borderline insulting those who are trying to help you improve your question and your experience. While you're quibbling w/us over the details, your system remains in a corrupted state

Comment: @Yesha: So what are you trying to say? Are you implying that all downvotes were by non-MySQL people, who failed to understand your question solely because it was about MySQL and thus not their area of expertise? Downvotes are an indication of what is wrong with the question, **not** of the fact that "I don't know X and don't like questions about X". Your question is unclear even to a non-MySQL person's eye. You are referring to jkavalik – right, he asked *two* clarifying questions in a single comment. Wasn't that a confirmation of the fact that your question was lacking details?

Comment: @Andriy : I appreciate your kind answer of explanation. Instead of saying bad answer or downvote .. I suggest user can comment on question so it will help to improve new members here rather than answer just like bad question.

Comment: @Yesha: But why be offended by downvotes in the first place? They are not a personal attack on you. At the very least, I firmly believe they've been used according to their purpose in your case, even though I myself haven't downvoted (yet). Just try re-reading your question from a perspective of someone completely unacquainted with your situation. That person would know only as much as you have revealed. And apparently that hasn't been enough to answer your question so far, as you can see for yourself. Downvotes are there to motivate you to improve it.

Comment: People post here to get solution or help to others.. so whenever I was actively looking answer for whatever detail I have. instead of help user says bad question or irrelevant that's not solution for new members. new members always looking for help how to solve and learn more about this helpful community.  I really like your kind answer to improve. thanks andriy!

Answer (score 7):

I've only just seen the question and my immediate problem with it is that it is asking about two very distinct problems:

- How to repair a table,

  and
- How to optimise a database.

The two issues may be related in your mind but they are still very different and should be asked about separately.

The second one, too, is *extremely* unspecific.